# How to Implement credit card and paypal transactions like fiverr in laravel

Tags: laravel, paypal, stripe-payments, braintree

I want to integrate transactions like in fiverr or upwork in my laravel website. I have tried braintree but that only helps in checkouts. I want to store the payments in my application and then send them to a bank account or paypal when the work is done just like fiverr or upwork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is to perform the transaction (send the payment to a bank/paypal) and create a records for your system, that the particular transaction happend, isn't it ? 
If it's the case, if you are to use Paypal, the best possible way is to read the paymentID and payerID from the session when the transaction is complete (using the payment gateway) and locally (in your application) perform an insert query to your table with the data been extracted with any other system specific additional details you may need to add to you record. 
If you use the following, 
https://github.com/net-shell/laravel-paypal 
you can easily modify the getDone() for this insertion.

Comment: actually my question is that is there a way to first transfer the amount from buyer's paypal or bank account to my website's paypal(checkout) and then transfer that amount from my website to the seller's paypal or bank account(payout)?

Comment: Try this : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Comment: Because as far as I can understand, your application is a facilitator among 2 sender and recipient ? If so, you can follow the guide, in the above link. Or rather you would have to perform 2 sequential operations of receiving and sending out.

Comment: if i go for 2 operation of receiving and then sending then does paypal provide api for both?

Comment: There is no actual operation to get down payment. What you could possibly do is to facilitate the customer to make the payment through your app, and make a record in your application's payment table that this recieption occured - with the amount (may be use a separate table for this or use a boolean attribute in the same payment table whether the amount is forwarded or not. So, the default value when the customer first pays would be a 'false'). Then, may be through, corn jobs (to automatically proceed) or a specific interface to specify the receiver from ur end and do the paypal payment.

Comment: By doing so, you would retrieve the already recorded payment from 'your' customer and update it to 'true' - that the payment has been forwarded to 'your' receiver after you check out your payment to your receiver. Got me ?? It's quite simple if you see this as 2 payments, in summary.

Comment: Thanks alot that really helped!